# Dynamic query creation with Array like implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create multiple queries with various weightages and properties.

The simplified version of couple of queries is this

```
SELECT 
    Emp_Id,  
    (30 * ISNULL(BMI,0) + 
    (20 * ISNULL(Height, 0) + 
    (10 * ISNULL(Eyesight, 0)) 
FROM
    MyTable1 
WHERE
    Category = 'Fighter'

SELECT 
    Emp_Id,  
    (10 * ISNULL(BMI,0) + 
    (10 * ISNULL(Height,0) +
    (20 * ISNULL(Skill,0) + 
    (40 * ISNULL(Eyesight,0)) 
FROM
    MyTable1 
WHERE
    Category = 'Sniper'
```

There are 100s of queries with different weightages and properties. So I wanted to create a table with weightages and properties, then create dynamic query which would be executed since it will be much easier to maintain.

This is my code so far:

```
/* Dummy Table Creation */

DECLARE @DummyWeightageTable TABLE (Category varchar(50), Fieldname varchar(50), Weightage real)

INSERT INTO @DummyWeightageTable 
VALUES ('Sniper', 'Eyesight', 40), 
       ('Sniper', 'BMI', 10), 
       ('Sniper', 'Height', 10), 
       ('Sniper', 'Skill', 20), 
       ('Fighter', 'Eyesight', 10), 
       ('Fighter', 'BMI', 30), 
       ('Fighter', 'Height', 20)

/* Actual Functionality */

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @delta VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @TempTableVariable TABLE (Fieldname varchar(50), Weightage real)

INSERT INTO @TempTableVariable 
    SELECT Fieldname, Weightage 
    FROM @DummyWeightageTable 
    WHERE Category = 'Sniper'

SET @sql = 'SELECT Emp_Id,'

/*Do below step for all rows*/
SELECT @delta = '(', Weightage, ' * ISNULL(', Fieldname, ',0) +' 
FROM @TempTableVariable

SET @sql = @sql + @delta + '0) from MyDataTable1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

TRUNCATE @TempTableVariable

INSERT INTO @TempTableVariable 
    SELECT Fieldname, Weightage 
    FROM @DummyWeightageTable 
    WHERE Category = 'Fighter'

SET @sql = 'SELECT Emp_Id,'

/*Do below step for all rows*/
SELECT @delta = '(', Weightage, ' * ISNULL(', Fieldname, ',0) +' 
FROM @TempTableVariable

SET @sql = @sql + @delta + '0) from MyDataTable1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

However SQL Server doesn't allow arrays. So I am getting an error when I try to populate variable `@delta`

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

I feel there must be some workaround for this but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I'd rather created `Weights` table  `Category` -> `BMI`, `Height`, `Skill` .. and used a plain join by `Category`

Comment: Thanks @Serg, but that doesn't work because of the complexity of the query. Above query is very simplified as compared to actual logic. So I really need it to be a query which will get executed.

Comment: We are unlikely to be able to help without knowing what the real problem is.

Comment: The problem is that the Weightages are part of code as of now and we would like it to be part of data. For example, If sniper eyesight weightage changes from 40 to 40.01, I dont want to touch my code for that. There are 20 million rows in MyDataTable1 and there will be about 500 rows in the weightages table.

Comment: Yes I have proposed to create a table for storing Weightages. Do it the same way as you store properties which must be weighted. Properties  are columns in the  MyDataTable1 in your queries, so weightages should be columns too.

Comment: Regardless of whether your approach is the correct one, your dynamic SQL is just full of errors. I have no idea where "arrays" come into it, but unless I am mistaken instead of `SELECT @delta = '(', Weightage, ' * ISNULL(', Fieldname, ',0) +' ` you want `SELECT @delta = concat('(', Weightage, ' * ISNULL(', Fieldname, ',0) +' )`, and `@sql` must be `nvarchar` not `varchar`. And then table `MyDataTable1` doesn't actually exist in the data provided. See [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FQwUmIm9) (of an you can't truncate table variables.

Comment: Thank You so much. I didn't create MyDataTable1. Wasn't really expecting anybody to take effort to create Fiddle. I didn't understand NVARCHAR vs VARCHAR though. Varchar is working fine too, may be because query only has English characters and may get quite complex so more size may be of greater use. I really appreciate your help. Thank you once again

Comment: Check the documentation `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` requires the input parameter to be `nvarchar` regardless of whether you are using non ascii chars.

Comment: Ok. So Execute will throw error. Got it. Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your dynamic SQL that I won't list it. And I won't comment on your design, it doesn't sound optimal, but as say the problem is a more complex than described its hard to comment.

Anyway, with what you have provided you can do the following:

- You can loop through all categories to avoid having to manually code them
- At a row level you need to `CONCAT` the values to create a dynamic string
- At a multi-row level you need to `STRING_AGG` the rows to build a single row

```
/* Dummy Table Creation */

DECLARE @DummyWeightageTable TABLE (
    Category varchar(50)
    , Fieldname varchar(50)
    , Weightage real
);

INSERT INTO @DummyWeightageTable
VALUES
('Sniper', 'Eyesight', 40), 
('Sniper', 'BMI', 10), 
('Sniper', 'Height', 10), 
('Sniper', 'Skill', 20), 
('Fighter', 'Eyesight', 10), 
('Fighter', 'BMI', 30), 
('Fighter', 'Height', 20);

/* Actual Functionality */

DECLARE @Category TABLE (
    Category varchar(50)
    , Done bit NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
);

-- Capture all categories so we can loop through them
INSERT INTO @Category (Category)
SELECT Category
FROM @DummyWeightageTable
GROUP BY Category;
  
-- Dynamic SQL must use nvarchar
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @delta NVARCHAR(MAX), @CurrentCategory varchar(50);

-- Loop through all categories
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Category WHERE Done = 0) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentCategory = Category FROM @Category WHERE Done = 0;
  
    -- Display the category at least for debugging
    SET @sql = 'SELECT Emp_Id, ' + @CurrentCategory + ', ';

    -- First concat the values required from each row
    -- Then string_agg then into a single string
    SELECT @delta = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('(', Weightage, ' * ISNULL(', Fieldname, ',0))'), ' + ')
    FROM @DummyWeightageTable
    WHERE Category = @CurrentCategory;

    SET @sql = @sql + @delta + ' from MyDataTable1;';

    -- This is how you debug dynamic SQL
    PRINT @sql;
    --EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    UPDATE @Category SET Done = 1 WHERE Category = @CurrentCategory;
END;
```

Returns:

```
SELECT Emp_Id, (10 * ISNULL(Eyesight,0)) + (30 * ISNULL(BMI,0)) + (20 * ISNULL(Height,0)) from MyDataTable1;
SELECT Emp_Id, (40 * ISNULL(Eyesight,0)) + (10 * ISNULL(BMI,0)) + (10 * ISNULL(Height,0)) + (20 * ISNULL(Skill,0)) from MyDataTable1;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ThD8RG2d)

Comment: Thank You so much..This works. I didn't know about String_Agg. So I was trying to loop through the rows. Using "Within Group(Order By Weightage desc)" with String_Agg takes care of my other requirement too.